# Create custom mouse event

Tags: javascript, events, easeljs

I'm working on a card game. I have a CardSet (custom Container object) that contains Cards (custom Container objects). I'd like to create custom events like: cardMouseOver and cardMouseOut so that I can listen to these card events like this:

```
cardSet.on('cardMouseOver', function(event) { set the event.card highlighted or anything );
cardSet.on('cardMouseOut', function(event) { set the event.card back to normal );
```

In the init block of the CardSet I added listeners to each cards:

```
card[i].on('mouseover', function (event) {
    var evt = new createjs.Event('cardMouseOver');
    evt.card = event.target;
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

The issue is when I move the mouse over the card it fires the over and out events right after each other. If I move the mouse it keeps firing these event like a mousemove. Any idea? Please ask if I wasn't clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: At startup, turn on mouseover only. In mouseover event, turn off mouseover and turn on mouseout. In mouseout event, turn off mouseout and turn on mouseover.

Comment: No luck, same result.

Comment: Did you try to attach to "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events?

Comment: Now I've just tried but didn't work. And I think mouseenter is dispatched when the mouse moves into the canvas.